# Having problems while trying to open jupyter notebook thorugh anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I tried to open jupyter notebook through anaconda prompt, and it shows an error message as:

[image: error message in chrome]

And:

[image: anaconda prompt]

Comment: That's not an error message. Those are instructions for how to use it.

Comment: Sorry,can u please elaborate how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste the URL that is generated into your browser: `http://localhost:8888/?token=....`

That will open Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: It's not an error message, it is generating a URL for you to use.